# C++ Wt framework on Ubuntu server

Tags: c++, server, frameworks, ubuntu-16.04, wt

I'm trying to use a c++ framework like Wt on a Ubuntu Server to try and run c++ programs. I've spent the last eight hours looking at different frameworks and trying to get Wt framework working on my Ubuntu 16.04 server. So I download the framework onto my server and can get one of their examples (such as hello) working on a virtual machine. When I try getting one of their examples working on my server and try to view the application, I can't.

So on my virtual machine all I have to do is run the program / application and then type in a web browser http:/0.0.0.0:8080. For my server I try the same thing but replaced the 0's with my IP address and then the 8080, nothing happens. How can I see my program, and not have to run the program every time on my server and then type in the special URL.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely due to parameters passed to your web app when running the example.  You should check the parameters passed to the web app and verify that they are correct and allow you to connect to the web app with your browser.  Although that seems to be a likely problem, there's not enough information in your question to know if that's an issue or not.

First step is to make sure the web app is actually running when  you attempt to connect to it from the browser. If it's not running, obviously, you won't be able to connect to it.

Also, you can read the console output from the web app when 1) you start up the app, and 2) when you attempt to connect to the app, in order to help determine the cause of your problem.

You say "nothing happens" when you attempt to connect to the web app on your server via browser.  Something must be happening, even if what's happening is a failure to connect:  Is the connection attempt failing? Is the connection timing out?  Are you getting an error page in response to the http request?

Other things to check are infrastructure issues, such as firewalls, router settings between your browser and the server, etc.  Can you run a web server such as Apache or nginx on the same server and connect to it?

More information would be helpful in determining the cause of your problem.  What is the console output of the web app when executed? What parameters are being passed to the web app in your command? What happens on the client end when you attempt to connect?

Comment: Didn't have enough room in the comment box here so I just posted it as an answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your application is running but some firewall configuration blocks access to port 8080.

To check if your application is running and listening, run netstat -na | grep LISTEN. There should be a process listening on address 0.0.0.0 on port 8080 (the address can also be your server's public IP address).